# Formal For Messed Up

Tags: formality

Is there a more formal phrase for "messed up" in this sentence?

"My monthly payment was messed up with another person's payment"

Thanks

Comment: *Confused*, perhaps?

Comment: Would replacing _messed_ with _mixed_ work? (The phrase  _messed up_ itself is euphemism for another _informal_ phrase).

Answer (score 2):

There some degree of opinion here, but I would go with **confuse**, sense 3, from [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confuse):

> to mistakenly think that one person or thing is another person or thing : to mistake (one person or thing) for another

Your sentence would then read

> My monthly payment was confused with another person's payment.

This is a sentence that sounds natural and clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes simple is better. Perhaps "switched" would work if you mean to say that you made your payment but it was recorded on the account of someone else.